How to find four numbers from the table that meet the requirements and find the four numbers with the largest sum?
In a 4x4 grid, it is required that each row and each column contains exactly one selected square. Enumerate all the four squares that are selected. And identify the selection that, among those that meet the aforementioned criteria, yields the maximum sum of the four numbers.

4x4 grid as follows:
Grid[{{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 24, 
   34, 44}}, Frame -> All]



numbers = {{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 
   24, 34, 44}}
allPermutations = Permutations[Range[1, 4]]
validSelections = 
 Select[allPermutations, 
  Module[{selection}, 
    selection = 
     numbers[[#[[1]]]] + numbers[[#[[2]] + 1]][[#[[2]]]] + 
       numbers[[#[[3]] + 2]][[#[[3]] + 1]] + 
       numbers[[#[[4]]]][[#[[4]]];
        Table[selection[[#]] == numbers[[i, #]], {i, 4}], {#, 
         4}] === {1, 1, 1, 1}] &]

The above code did not produce the correct result.

There is a resource function in the repositiory that solves this problem exactly using integer linear optimization, and it will even work for very large matrices: ResourceFunction["MinSumPermutation"][-numbers] gives {2, 3, 4, 1}. Try, for example, with numbers = RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}, {1000, 1000}] to check that this is an amazing resource function!

(-1) I don't even see your effort in writing a question. The description of the question is simply not understandable, what do you mean by "each row and each column contains exactly one selected square", "four squares", etc?

A = {{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 24, 34, 44}};

MaximalBy[MapThread[Part, {A, #}] & /@ Permutations[Range[4]], Total]
(*    {{21, 33, 43, 15}}    *)

If you want the intermediate list as well:
MapThread[Part, {A, #}] & /@ Permutations[Range[4]]
(*    {{11, 22, 33, 44}, {11, 22, 43, 34}, {11, 33, 22, 44},
       {11, 33, 43, 24}, {11, 42, 22, 34}, {11, 42, 33, 24},
       {21, 12, 33, 44}, {21, 12, 43, 34}, {21, 33, 13, 44},
       {21, 33, 43, 15}, {21, 42, 13, 34}, {21, 42, 33, 15},
       {31, 12, 22, 44}, {31, 12, 43, 24}, {31, 22, 13, 44},
       {31, 22, 43, 15}, {31, 42, 13, 24}, {31, 42, 22, 15},
       {40, 12, 22, 34}, {40, 12, 33, 24}, {40, 22, 13, 34},
       {40, 22, 33, 15}, {40, 33, 13, 24}, {40, 33, 22, 15}}    *)

MaximalBy[%, Total]
(*    {{21, 33, 43, 15}}    *)

For much larger systems, exhaustive searching of all permutations is impossible. But we can do a Metropolis–Hastings "Monte Carlo" stochastic search:
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 30;
m = 9;
A = RandomInteger[{0, m}, {n, n}];

ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"][
  Total[MapThread[Part, {A, #}]] &, n,
  Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
(*    {{{12, 5, 2, 8, 3, 18, 23, 24, 30, 16, 13, 28, 25, 15, 10,
         26, 1, 4, 11, 19, 7, 14, 6, 17, 9, 29, 22, 20, 27, 21}}, 260.}

This MaximizeOverPermutations resource function has fine-grained options for controlling the stochastic search.

very neat +1 :)

m = {{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 24, 
    34, 44}};
p = Permutations[Range[4]];
cases = Extract[m, #] & /@ Thread[{Range[4], #}] & /@ p;
sums = Total /@ cases;
Extract[cases, Position[sums, Max[sums]]]
mx = MapAt[Style[#, Purple, Background -> Green] &, sums, {10}];
pos = Thread[{Range[4], #}] & /@ p;
gds = Grid[MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, m, #], Frame -> All] & /@ pos;
Partition[Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ Thread[{mx, gds}], 
  4] // Grid



As far as I understand, all 4! permutation correspond to valid choice. For the permutation {i1,i2,i3,i4}, just take (1,i1), (2,i2), (3,i3) and (4,i4) elements from the 4x4 matrix. This rule is exactly the same as the definition of matrix determinant.
numbers = {{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 24, 34, 44}};
allPermutations = Permutations[Range[1, 4]];
allchoices = 
 Extract[numbers, Transpose[{Range[4], #}]] & /@ allPermutations

 (* {{11, 22, 33, 44}, {11, 22, 43, 34}, {11, 33, 22, 44}, {11, 
  33, 43, 24}, {11, 42, 22, 34}, {11, 42, 33, 24}, {21, 12, 33, 
  44}, {21, 12, 43, 34}, {21, 33, 13, 44}, {21, 33, 43, 15}, {21, 42, 
  13, 34}, {21, 42, 33, 15}, {31, 12, 22, 44}, {31, 12, 43, 24}, {31, 
  22, 13, 44}, {31, 22, 43, 15}, {31, 42, 13, 24}, {31, 42, 22, 
  15}, {40, 12, 22, 34}, {40, 12, 33, 24}, {40, 22, 13, 34}, {40, 22, 
  33, 15}, {40, 33, 13, 24}, {40, 33, 22, 15}} *)

  MaximalBy[allchoices, Total]

  (* {{21, 33, 43, 15}} *)


A = {{11, 21, 31, 40}, {12, 22, 33, 42}, {13, 22, 33, 43}, {15, 24, 34, 44}};
MaximalBy[{A #, Total[A #, 2]} & /@ Permutations@IdentityMatrix@4, Last]


{{$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 21 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 33 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 43 \\
 15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$,112}}

